# Reactjs using map func with json file

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I'm learning React and I got struggle using map function to present data from json file.
It do show the loading data before the data load but after that nothing.
Print the state.questions in line 6 and do show that there is something in it.
[image: my code]

[image: State]

Answer (score 3):

You need the return statement. Or remove the {}

```
state.questions.map(ques => {return (<p key={ques.id}>{ques.question}</p>) })
```

Answer (score 0):

What i can see in your console `questions` is list of dict inside `state.questions`.

```
{state.questions.questions.map(q => {return (<p key={q.id}>{.question}</p>) })
```